# seleting an option from a drop down menu using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm having the following problem. I have a dropdown that is hidden so when I make the Select and run the test i get the following error:

*selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated*

below is the code i have been trying:

```
cur=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("currencyCode"))
cur.select_by_visible_text('USD')
```

below is the html syntax of the code:

```
<div class="form-group true-grid-3">
            <label for="currencyCode">Currency</label>
            <select id="currencyCode" name="criteria.currencyCode" class="form-control" style="display: none;">
                <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
                <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
                <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
                <option value="JPY">JPY</option>
                <option value="USD">USD</option>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `display: none` to `display: block` in the css property so that the element becomes visible.

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('criteria.currencyCode').style.display = 'block';")
```

Comment: This solution works perfect if i change the id from "criteria.currencyCode" to "currencyCode"            Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to call drop-down `driver.find_element_by_id("currencyCode").click()` and then, when options became visible, choose required option `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//option[@value="USD"]').click()`

Comment: kept showing the same error andersson, it worked if i changed the display from "none" to "block" using javascript code. Thanks !